# AIME I 2023 Problem 15 seeking for some better and simpler solutions, approaches and explanations than AOPS .

Tags: real-analysis, complex-numbers

Find the largest prime number $p<1000$ for which there exists a complex number $z$ satisfying

the real and imaginary part of $z$ are both integers;
$|z|=\sqrt{p},$ and
there exists a triangle whose three side lengths are $p,$ the real part of $z^{3},$ and the imaginary part of $z^{3}.$

Well it has some nice solutions but I am posting it here with hope to get some more simpler and better approaches and solutions.

Comment: $z=a+bi$, $a^2+b^2=p$, $z^3=(a^3-3ab^2)+(3a^2b-b^3)i$, that's a start....

Comment: What's next ???

Comment: Hey i wanted to ask can't we actually make use of Ravi's substitution here ??

Comment: I don't know anyone named Ravi.

Comment: @GerryMyerson oh that was lil funny but I was talking about Ravi substitution which is splitting side lengths of a triangle into x+y,y+z and z+x 

Comment: Never heard of it, but if it works for you, go for it.

Comment: Well sir , can u please explain how does the substitution works for this particular problem 

Comment: I don't know whether it does any good in this problem. You'd have $x+y=a^2+b^2$, $y+z=a^3-3ab^2$, $x+z=3a^2b-b^3$, and you can solve that system for $x,y,z$ in terms of $a,b$, and maybe something will come of that, and maybe not. You won't know, until you try it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson right words sir 